# Links in Django

Tags: python, django, hyperlink

I'm trying to get my links working in Django.  All the URLs work when typed in, but I can't figure out the internal navigation.  They are all of the format app.com/storename/pagename, so if I'm on app.com/shoestore/products and click on location, I should go to app.com/shoestore/location.  I'm losing the shoestore part.

Here's a sample view:

```
def homepage(request, store_subdomain):
    store_db, store_products = database_selector(store_subdomain)
    return render_to_response('base.html', 
            {'store_name': store_db.name, 'store_subdomain':store_subdomain})
```

My urls.py:

urlpatterns = patterns('',

```
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^(?P<store_subdomain>\w+)/$', homepage),
url(r'^(?P<store_subdomain>\w+)/products/$', products),
url(r'^(?P<store_subdomain>\w+)/shoppingcart/$', shoppingcart),
url(r'^(?P<store_subdomain>\w+)/checkout/$', checkout),
url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
             {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

)

and my navigation tag:

```
<li><a href = "/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href = "/products/"}>Products</a></li> 
<li><a href = "/location/">Location</a></li>
<li><a href="mailto:{{store_db.email}}">Email Us</a> </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use named [url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns).

`url(r'^(?P<store_subdomain>\w+)/$', homepage, name='home')`

```
<li><a href="{% url home store_subdomain %}">Home</a></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

`url(r'^(?P<store_subdomain>\w+)/$', 'homepage', name='homepage'),`

```
<a href="{% url home store_subdomain=value %}">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic here. you wrote root binded urls in navigation. in this case I would suggest to use reverse() function from django's urlresolvers.